# flutter change bottomNavigationBar(TabBar) height

Tags: dart, flutter, tabbar

I just found a way to change the height of AppBar with PreferredSize().

But I still not found a way modify the height of BottomNavigationBar and TabBar. Such widgets all hard coded, is there a way can change the widget height for thinner BottomBar and TabBar.

Answer (score 3):

`_BottomNavigationBarState` class is private, and in it's `build` method there is string `BoxConstraints(minHeight: kBottomNavigationBarHeight + additionalBottomPadding)`. There is no way to change this height without customization this class

Comment: Yes, you can do that but it is generally not a good idea to hard code that height. Otherwise depending on pixels on your device, the UI will not look consistent. If it is looking good in lower pixels phones, then it may look weird on higher pixels phone. So, you may want to add conditions there too.